# How to explain on an interview than i am pursuing a M.Sc. and i need to leave earlier for the time being?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, hours

I think the question is pretty self-explanatory.
I have two interviews in front of me but i currently doing my **M.Sc.** and some of my classes are starting about the time I should be still working in most companies, working (about 16:30). Most companies are following the 9-5.

*How to handle this?* It is better to:

- getting straight and ask for early leave some days / late work other days
- ask my professors than I will be late specific days?
- not asking at all, increasing my chances of getting hired but getting careless about M.Sc. schedule?

Comment: Can you give us some context about the jobs you're applying for? Some positions may be more or less sensitive to working hours. For instance, if you're going for something with a customer- or public- facing role, you may NEED to be available during certain hours, versus something in a back office role (ie software development) where adjusting your working hours by half an hour may be a total non-issue.

Comment: @dwizum, sorry for the delay... I am applying for software developing jobs, one of which has one subsidiary office at London (i located at Thessaloniki, Greece). Yes, they have clients on another cities and counties. Yes, i initially thought that the whole issue would be half-an-hour, more or less but depends on the position itself, being a developer or client-contacting position. I actually do not know the position, i just sent my CV and it actually happened they wanted to hire a number of position like DBA Admins, Sys Admins, Web devs and such positions. I am in the dark as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Universities will give a lot of leeway to students in terms of studying around their work. It's their revenue stream and they have a big stake in you being successful.

So I recommend you try that avenue first before thinking of involving your paid employment in your problems.

> not asking at all, increasing my chances of getting hired but getting careless about M.Sc. schedule?

Don't do this, your masters is a major investment in your future and career, treat it seriously as such.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your availability comes up during the interview, I would wait until you have an offer from the company before discussing having to leave early to attend university classes. One thing you could offer to do if they don't like you working fewer hours, is to start early to compensate. Just watch out that you don't set yourself up for a burn-out.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Yes, coming earlier is certainly not an issue, the lateness is. I like your approach, waiting for the green light then starting asking for such things.